# In OS X, I want to change to a non-standard keyboard shortcut for switching spaces

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, apple-expose

In System Preferences > Expose and Spaces > Spaces Tab > to switch between spaces, there is a drop down list that allows you to select a modifier key and the arrows. The arrows are so far away from the rest of the keyboard! I want to bind to the vim keys (h, j, k, l) for (left, down, up, and right). On my ubuntu machine, I push the equivalent of command-option-j to go down a space. Does anyone know how to change to a non-standard keyboard shortcut on osx?

Comment: This question should be moved to apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Costique.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4972/in-os-x-i-want-to-change-to-a-non-standard-keyboard-shortcut-for-switching-space

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.  The only thing I can think of at the moment, would be to bind specific keystrokes for specific spaces.  That can be done by going to the Keyboard control panel, selecting Expose & Spaces, and then customizing the keys there.